# Custom tag Java Jsp - How to set attribute base on a dropdown list selection

Tags: java, html, jsp, tags

I have a Java Jsp custom tag with attributes. These attributes are selectable from a drop down list. So how can I set attribute to my custom tag base on the selection from the dropdown list?

For example:

```
<select>
   <option>A</option>
   <option>B</option>
   <option>C</option>
</select>
<prf:customTag atribute1="[***]"/>
```

So [***] is set to "A" if I selected A from the dropdown list, "B" if I selected B, and "C" so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select must be within 'form' tags as follows:

```
<form method="POST" action="myPage.jsp">
  <select name="optionSelected">
     <option>A</option>
     <option>B</option>
     <option>C</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
```

The current page is called myPage.jsp and when the form is submitted the value selected from the drop-down will be passed to the jsp page in the request parameter and therefore can be retrived and used as the input to the cutom tag.

```
<prf:customTag atribute1="${ param.optionSelected }"/>
```

The option selected from the drop-down list will be retrived from the parameters posted to the myPage.jsp and inserted in the custom tag using Exxpression Language.